# Switch VS If else in Fragments android

Tags: java, performance

I am making a tour guide app using fragments and tablayout
i made a viewpager adapter to navigate through the tabs 
in the getItem method i use If else statement like this

```
   if (position == 0) {
        return new InfoFragment();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return new HotelsFragment();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return new RestaurantsFragment();
    } else {
        return new TemplesFragment();
    }
```

and I notice that I also can use Switch statement like this

```
 switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new InfoFragment();
        case 1:
            return new HotelsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new RestaurantsFragment();
        default:
            return new TemplesFragment();

    }
```

so I wonder which one should I use..
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

The switch is considered faster that's the only difference I know. If I have to choose I will choose switch.